# How to prove $x^2=-1$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ iff $p=1\mod 4$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be prime and let $\mathbb{Q}_p$ denote the field of $p$-adic numbers.
Is there an elementary way to prove $x^2=-1$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ iff $p=1\mod 4$?

I need this result, but I cannot find a reference. Can some recommend a good book or a set of (easily available) lecture notes to help me out?

Answer (score 4):

Are you familiar about number theory? This is equivalent to saying that $x^2 \equiv -1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ iff $p \equiv 1$ (mod $4$). But this is a basic fact on number theory, since
\begin{equation*}
\Big( \frac{-1}{p} \Big) = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = 1 \text{ iff } p \equiv 1 (\text{ mod }4)
\end{equation*}

Comment: But $\mathbb Q_p$ is a completion of $\mathbb Q$ and thus has characteristic $0$, not $p$?

Comment: Yes, but since you are searching for solutions of $x^2 = -1$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, in fact you are searching solutions in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, since $|x|^2_p = |-1|_p = 1$. So, you are searching for $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $x^2 = -1$. Finally, recall that there is the reduction map

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{Z}_p \longrightarrow \mathbb{F}_p
\end{equation*}

given by $x = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i p^i \mapsto \overline{x} = a_i$ ($a_i \in \{ 0,1,...,p-1\}$).

You see you need a little of background about p-adic numbers.

Comment: IMO you should specifically list the need to use Hensel lifting (or Hensel's lemma) for the implication "there is a solution in $\Bbb{F}_p$" $\implies$ "there is a solution in $\Bbb{Q}_p$".

Comment: Also, the argument fails for $p = 2$, in which case $(X+1)^2 + 1 = X^2 + 2X + 2$ is an Eisenstein polynomial and therefore $X^2 + 1$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 0):

Following Euler Criterion

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion

$-1$ is a quadratic residue if $(-1)^{\frac{(p-1)}2}=1$

which happens only when $\frac{(p-1)}2$ is even

so $p-1$ is divisible by 4

so $p\equiv1 (mod4)$

the book i would follow for number theory is **Introduction to number theory** by **Hua Loo Keng**

this is a fairly comprehensive book can a bit a too much for elementary course so depending on your syllabus you may want to use an elementary text like **Elementary number theory by Rosen.**